# File Input/output and searching

Tags: c, io

I need to open a file, then count the number of time a certain sequence appears in the file, with space being ignore. The file name and the sequence are entered by the using through the command line. Here's my approach: I open the file, then store the content to an array, then remove all the space from that array and store it to another array. Then, I search for sequence and count the number of times it appear. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
char *tempRaw;
char *temp;
int size;
//Input check
if(argc != 3) 
{
fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s Input Search\n", argv[0]);
exit(1);
}
//Open files
FILE *input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
//Check for file
if(input == NULL) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file: %s\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
}
//Get the file size
fseek (input,0,SEEK_END);
size = ftell(input);
rewind(input);
//Allocate memory for the strings
tempRaw = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
temp = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*size);

//Copy the file's content to the string
int result =0;
int i;
fread(tempRaw,sizeof(char),size,input);
//Remove the blanks
removeBlanks(temp,tempRaw);
fclose(input);

char *pointer;
//Search for the sequence
pointer = strchr(pointer,argv[2]);
// If the sequence is not found
if (pointer == NULL)
{
    printf("%s appears 0 time",argv[2]);
    return;
}
else if (pointer != NULL)
{
    //Increment result if found
    result ++;
}
while (pointer != NULL)
{
    //Search the next character
    pointer = strchr(pointer+1,argv[2]);
    //Increment result if the sequence is found
    if (pointer != NULL)
    {
        result ++;
    }
    //If the result is not found, pointer turn to NULL the the loop is break 
}

printf(" Sequence : %s\n",temp);
printf("%s appears %d time(s)\n",argv[2],result);
}

void removeBlanks( char *dest, const char *src)
{
//Copy source to destination
strcpy(dest,src);
char *old = dest;
char *new = old;
//Remove all the space from destination
while (*old != '\0') 
{
    // If it's not a space, transfer and increment new.

    if (*old != ' ')
    {
        *new++ = *old;
    }
    // Increment old no matter what.

    old++;
}

// Terminate the new string.

*new = '\0';

}
```

I tested it, and I'm having problem with getting the content from the file. Sometimes it works, but most of the time, all I got is an empty string.

Comment: That indentation doesn't help readability... also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858), and `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so it's redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code and the compiler should have given you warnings about them (and don't ignore the compiler):

First functions should be declared, not just defined so add:

```
void removeBlanks( char *dest, const char *src);
```

before main. According to the C99 standard (*5.1.2.2.1 Program startup*) `main` should be declared with a return value like `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` and you should add the appropriate `return`statements.

And like pointed out above [casting malloc is not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

The problems above isn't why it isn't working however... it because you use the [strchr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) function on the wrong variable and in the wrong way:

```
pointer = strchr(pointer,argv[2]);
```

should be

```
pointer = strchr(temp, *argv[2]);
```

because `temp`is the pointer to the contents you read from the file and `strchr`needs a `char`as the second argument, not a `char *`. If you want to search for a string you would have to use [strstr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) and that takes a `char *` like:

```
pointer = strstr(temp, argv[2]);
```

Also, since you remove the blanks from `tempRaw`and store the new string in `temp` the second string will be shorter and will get garbage at the end so you should initialize the memory like:

```
tempRaw = calloc(1, size);
```

There might be other errors too, but these changes made it work for me...

Comment: the `calloc` is not necessary, `removeBlanks()` is null-terminating the output array.

Comment: @EdwardClements Hmm, it should but I get garbage at the end of `printf("Sequence:\n%s\n\n",temp);`if I don't use calloc.

Comment: Still not working on some cases though. for example: If I'm searching for GT in the file contain "GAGAGAGAGAGAAAAAAGGGGGTTAATATATTTTGATAC". I got 12 instead of 1. Trying to go through my code to see what's wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: also need the changes in the other original answer: `size = ftell(input) + 1;` and `tempRaw[size - 1] = '\0';` to null-terminate the contents of the file

Comment: @NguyễnDuy Read what I added about `strchr`and `strstr`. You want to use `strstr`. When using `strchr`you count the number of `G`not `GT`, for that change it to use `strstr`.

Comment: @jpw : It stills not work on some cases. I tried to search for AA in." TTCCTCTTTCTCGACTCCATCTTCGCGGTAGCTGGGACCGCCGTTCAGTC
GCCAATATGCAGCTCTTTGTCCGCGCCCAGGAGCTACACACCTTCGAGGT
GACCGGCCAGGAAACGGTCGCCCAGATCAAGGCTCATGTAGCCTCACTGG
AGGGCATTGCCCCGGAAGATCAAGTCGTGCTCCTGGCAGGCGCGCCCCTG
GAGGATGAGGCCACTCTGGGCCAGTGCGGGGTGGAGGCCCTGACTACCCT
GGAAGTAGCAGGCCGCATGCTTGGAGGTAAAGTTCATGGTTCCCTGGCCC
GTGCTGGAAAAGTGAGAGGTCAGACTCCTAAGGTGGCCAAACAGGAGAAG
AAGAAGAAGAAGACAGGTCGGGCTAAGCGGCGGATGCAGTACAACCGGCG
CTTTGTCAACGTTGTGCCCACCTTTGGCAAGAAGAAGGGCCCCAATGCCA
ACTCTTAAGTCTTTTGTAATTCTGGCTTTCTCTAATAAAAAAGCCACTTA
GTTCAGTCAAAAAAAAAA"

Comment: And got 44 instead of 45 :(

Comment: Do you think it's because of those cases when the sequence is like AAA. Which should be 2 instead of 1?

Comment: @NguyễnDuy No, I think it's because the file string `temp`is one char too short. Try adding a white space at the end of the file and it will be correct. To fix this I think you need to include the changes suggested by Edward Clements in the comment above.

Comment: @jpw You mind checking the file out? It still not working though :(
http://www.mediafire.com/?43sgdo4i1q8qu5b

Comment: @NguyễnDuy When I ran the code you linked to with the data above I got 45 hits for AA; I don't know why you get 44 :\

Comment: @jpw whattttttttttttt :( Can you try the same sequence but searching for GA then? I got 29, it should be 31.

Comment: @jpw I know what the problem is now, but I dont know how to fix it. In my test file, the sequence is laid out like this:
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA(end line)                 
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA(end line)                   "

And when I put it all on a line, it got 45. Any idea on how to fix that? Try using this file and you'll see what I mean. http://www.mediafire.com/download/tcjsy15qy199za8/1.txt

Comment: @NguyễnDuy You need to remove the newlines. You could change `(*old != ' ')`to `(isalpha(*old))` in the removeBlanks function.

Comment: @jpw +1 for your patience!